# picking photos from facebook to my website

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I am taking user information from Facebook to my website using their API, in php, codeigniter. It is like following:

```
$fbme = $this->facebook->api('/'.$uid);
```

It gives me the user information from facebook.

I want to get some photos like 10 or 20 more. Hence I am trying like following:

```
$photos = $this->facebook->api('/'.$uid.'/photos?limit=12');
```

But it returns me an empty array. Can anyone help me soon?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo?locale=en_GB). It might have some answers for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos

> A user access token with user_photos permission is required to see all photos that person is tagged in or has uploaded.

Also, keep in mind that you need to go through a review process to make user_photos available for everyone: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/login

And of course you can only get photos of the authorized User, so `/me/photos` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Of course I tried but always it gives me an empty string.

Comment: then there just are not photos, or you did not use a correct user token (ALWAYS use /me/photos, never with the user id), or you tried with a user who is not app admin/developer/tester.

Comment: I just using /me/photos and connection is also ok. I want to take photos for every user. I have photos in my account but it is showing empty array. I am not clear about your answer "user who is not app admin/developer/tester." can you clear me? Thanks.